# How To Convert Multidimensional Array To Another Format Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have data from a database that I want to convert to another format. The data is in the form of an array as below

```php
$array = [
    ['type 1', 'Country 1', 243],
    ['type 1', 'Country 2', 500],
    ['type 1', 'Country 3', 400],
    ['type 2', 'Country 1', 234],
    ['type 2', 'Country 2', 1234],
    ['type 2', 'Country 3', 1400],
    ['type 3', 'Country 1', 222],
    ['type 3', 'Country 2', 25],
    ['type 3', 'Country 3', 120],
];
```

How to convert array above with php to array like this below:

```php
$toArray = [
    [
        'name' => 'type 1',
        'data' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Country 1',
                'y' => 243
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Country 2',
                'y' => 500
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Country 3',
                'y' => 400
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'type 2',
        'data' => [
            [
                'name' => 'Country 1',
                'y' => 234
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Country 2',
                'y' => 1234
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Country 3',
                'y' => 1400
            ],
        ]
    ],
    ...
];
```

Code so far

```
$toArray = []; 
foreach($models as $key => $model) { 
    $type = [ 'name' => $model->type, 'data' => [] ]; 
    if(in_array($type, $toArray)) { 
        continue; 
    } 
    $toArray[] = $type; 
}
```

I'm confuse about this, can someone guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier way would be to use the model name as the key to the array and check if it isn't already set.  If not it will add the name and a blank data element (similar to what you are already doing).  Then it will add the other information to this data element.

```
$toArray = [];
foreach($array as $key => $model) {
    if ( !isset($toArray[$model->type]) )  {
        $toArray[$model->type] = [ 'name' => $model->type, 'data' => [] ];
    }
    $toArray[$model->type]['data'][] = [ 'name' => $model->country, 
                'y' => $model->value ];
}

// Remove keys if not needed
$toArray = array_values($toArray);
```

Comment: You're right Nigel, my data($array) is an object from active record, so name will be $model->type, country will be $model->country, and y will be $model->value

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate using `foreach`

```
foreach($array as $v){
  if(isset($final[$v[0]])){
    $final[$v[0]]['data'][] = ['name' => $v[1], 'y' => $v[2]];
  }else{
    $final[$v[0]] = ['name' => $v[0],'data' =>[
            ['name' => $v[1], 'y' => $v[2]]
        ]
    ];
  }
}
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/lu7bk